# External Java Authentication for IBM Cognos 8

Tags: java, authentication, cognos-8

Is it possible to right/configure a custom authentication java module, such that the authentication is done by java. If authentication is true then pass only loggedin user id to cognos and do business logic based on this like drop down or data population.

The password will not be accessible to cognos, only the user id.
The userid and password match is done by java application.

I have read this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/security/cognos8_platform/page517.html But i think cognos need the password also..

Comment: some 20 views but no answers :( :'(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756007/sso-between-java-ee-and-cognos-application and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/security/cognos8_platform/page517.html helped me...